# Set vendors on Context Manager (Custom Access Level)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-workspace

I am looking to block Google Workspace sign in for any user who do not have my agent on their computer. I have seen a new parameter "vendor" appearing on the list below. This new parameter seems to be designed for third parties:
https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/custom-access-level-spec#device

However, I do not find any documentation on how I can fill this setting on the device. Any hint?